How can I chain commands in a useful way?
I want to assert the following structure:


<app-toggler data-cy="toggler">
  <button id="1" data-cy="1">
    <rows data-cy="rows">
      <span>Title</span>
     </rows>
    <textarea>
      <text-rows data-cy="textarea">
        <div title="Value1" data-cy="app-textarea-val1">
          <span>Value1</span>
         </div>
         <div title="Value2" data-cy="app-textarea-val2"><!---->
          <span>Value2</span>
         </div>
         <div title="Value3" data-cy="app-textarea-val3">
          <span>Value3</span>
         </div>
        </text-rows>
       </textarea>
   </button>
   <button id="2" data-cy="2">
    <rows data-cy="rows">
      <span>Titletwo</span>
     </rows>
    <textarea>
      <text-rows data-cy="textarea">
        <div title="Value1two" data-cy="app-textarea-val1">
          <span>Value1two</span>
         </div>
         <div title="Value2two" data-cy="app-textarea-val2"><!---->
          <span>Value2two</span>
         </div>
         <div title="Value3two" data-cy="app-textarea-val3">
          <span>Value3two</span>
         </div>
        </text-rows>
       </textarea>
   </button>
 </app-toggler>



I want to know, if e.g. :
"Title, Value1, Value2, Value3"isOneOf.Buttons.Text()

examples:
"Title, Value1, Value2, Value3".isOneOf.Buttons.Text() => true
"Titletwo, Value1, Value2, Value3".isOneOf.Buttons.Text() => false
"Title, Value1two, Value2three, Value3four".isOneOf.Buttons.Text() => false
It's unclear to me how to chain commands in a correct and useful way to get the required information right. I hope I described it correctly.

What you want to assert isn't clear to me. Is it that you want to check that the text value of one of the elements (what I think are the comma-separated values in the quotation marks) is a button? Can you provide a sample Cypress code of what you've tried?

First, thanks for your answer. What i want to assert, is there a button inside of the app-toggler, where the text values are equal to "Title, Value1, Value2, Value3". I will present you some things i tried tomorrow. But eg. I tried to store all text  values in an array like so myarr =  ["Title, Value1, Value2, Value3","Titletwo, Value1two, Value2two, Value3two"] and than assert it like  expect("Title, Value1, Value2, Value3".to.be.oneOf(myarr). But these seemed to me wrong. i tried something with .filter but i didnt get the correct texts.

This looks like nonesense code to me - why would you have a textarea on a button? And why would it's text be HTML markup?

For the text you basically chain .should('contain', ...).and('contain', ...) assertions, e.g
cy.get('button#1')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contain', 'Value1')
  .and('contain', 'Value2')
  .and('contain', 'Value3')

where .invoke('text') is getting the full text of all the children of the button and using .should('contain', ...) is effectively chopping up the combined text and looking for individual values.
If you want to be more precise, for example the text contains other text i.e Value1two contains Value1 so it's a double match, you need to work with the spans.
const values = ['Title', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
cy.get('button#1')
  .find('span')
  .each(($span,i) => {
    cy.wrap($span).invoke('text').should('eq', values[i])
  })

This also checks the ordering is correct.
If you're not checking text but say title=... attributes you need to extract those instead
const values = ['Title', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
cy.get('button#1')
  .find('span')
  .each(($span,i) => {
    cy.wrap($span).attr('attr', title).should('eq', values[i])
  })


As far as i understand, this will assert if button1 contains the given values. i try to find out whether one of the buttons contains the given values. Thats the chain i tried to figure out, but could not solve.

You can drop the #1 part of button#1 and it will give all the button, then the should().and() assertions should give you a filter effect.

Cypress recommends that you know the expected format of the HTML, so you should craft the test in such a way that you know you are testing the values of button#1 - rather than trying the search through all the button. But there may be other factors that are not apparent from the example.

Hi again, i appreciate your help. but none of the obove things work.

Hi again, i appreciate your help. but none of the obove things work. your first example allows "Value1two, Value2". the second example failes, because we are wrapping all spans, and than we try to assert the span from the second button for which we do not have an assertion array given. failes than like so: expected Value2two to include undefined

the third one failes with cy.wrap(...).attr is not a function

Since you look for Title as first value, why not use it in the query?
Use combination contains() and regex /^Title$/ to make exact match.
const values = ['Title', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
cy.contains('button rows span', /^Title$/)
  .parents('button')
  .find('span')
  .each(($span,i) => {
    cy.wrap($span).invoke('text').should('eq', values[i])
  })


Hi, thanks for your help. This example does not work due to different problems. 1. span has no title. the parent div has. Another problem ist, that the the row, where we have the title inside, has not "title" attribut. I am still try to get it solved. But I guess, i can not assert, if one of the buttons has the given values from values array. it might fail in the one or the other way.

i try to share some of the things i have tried so far:
using buttons text in an array. the problem is, that the buttons[i].join() does not work.
let values = "title, Value1, Value2, Value3"

exp_assert_adress_in_popup_exist(values){
let buttons = []
        cy.get(app-toggler)
            .children('button')
            .each(($button)=>{
                let button = []
                cy.get($button)
                    .invoke('attr', 'data-cy')
                    .then(($buttonselector) => {
                        if ($buttonselector.includes("title")){
                            this.get_element_value_from_button($buttonselector, "title").then(($title) =>{
                                let title= $title
                                button.push($title)
                            })
                            this.get_element_value_from_button($buttonselector, "val1").then(($val1) =>{
                                let val1= $val1
                                button.push($val1)
                            })
                            this.get_element_value_from_button($buttonselector, "val2").then(($val2) =>{
                                let val2= $val2
                                button.push($val2)
                            })
                            this.get_element_value_from_button($buttonselector, "val3").then(($val3) =>{
                                let val3= $val3
                                button.push($val3)
                            })
                            
                buttons.push(button)
        })
        
        this.buttonsarray_contains_entry(buttons, values)

    }

   get_element_value_from_button(button, label){
        let element = `[data-cy$="-${label}"]`
        return cy.get(`[data-cy="${button}"]`).children().find(element).invoke('text')
    }

buttonsarray_contains_entry(buttons, values){
        for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            expect(values).to.be.oneOf(buttons[i].join())
        }
    }

